# ros2 run - symbol not found on custom msg

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've defined a custom message as described below.

Obstacle.msg:

```
geometry_msgs/Point32 polygon
float32 size_uncertainty
uint8 obstacle_class
```

..and the msg and associated publisher that uses it compiles just fine.

When I go to execute the node, the wheels fall off:

```
$ ros2 run obstacle_publisher obstacle_publisher
    /home/paul/code/eclipse_ws/ROS2/install/obstacle_publisher/lib/obstacle_publisher/obstacle_publisher: symbol lookup error: 
    /home/paul/code/eclipse_ws/ROS2/install/obstacle_msgs/lib/libobstacle_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: 
    undefined symbol: _ZN13geometry_msgs3msg24typesupport_fastrtps_cpp27max_serialized_size_Point32ERbm
```

I have `std_msgs` and `geometry_msgs` set with `depend` in the package.xml of both the package that creates the message (obstacle_msgs) and the package that uses the message (obstacle_publisher).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Sincerely, Paul.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326008/ros2-run---symbol-not-found-on-custom-msg/) by [AwooOOoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42876/awoooooo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2019-06-17

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without seeing the code it is hard to tell for sure.

But my guess is that your `obstacle_msgs` package does not list the dependencies properly when generating the messages.

When invoking `rosidl_generate_interfaces` in CMake, the message dependencies need to be specified using the `DEPENDENCIES` argument.

```
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${my_msg_files}
  ${my_srv_files}
  DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs my_custom_msgs
)
```

For example, here is the line used in the `sensor_msgs` package: https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/8fa6936cf0a5fd743e1456a88b2c1450c173e7aa/sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt#L54

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 18

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AwooOOoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/42876/awoooooo/) on 2019-06-18**:
Thank you,
That was it =). I'd forgotten to include the msg dependencies.

Sincerely, Paul.

**Comment by [MH_Ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/49436/mh_ahmed/) on 2020-03-02**:
Thanks to Allah, you saved my day.

Great thanks!
Mohamed

**Comment by [lokeshtarala](https://answers.ros.org/users/76078/lokeshtarala/) on 2021-06-14**:
Thank you, it worked I used sensor_msgs to build a custom message adding dependencies worked for me..

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
"msg/PixyVector.msg"
**DEPENDENCIES sensor_msgs**
)

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2021-10-01**:
Thanks for this. This is unfortunately not mentioned in https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces.html . Where can I report this?

**Comment by [mihota](https://answers.ros.org/users/3807/mihota/) on 2022-03-03**:
Can't believe they missed this in the tutorial. Anyone know and can point me to how to edit the tutorials?

**Comment by [RFRIEDM_Trimble](https://answers.ros.org/users/73619/rfriedm_trimble/) on 2022-07-10**:
This is still not documented on the humble tutorials. I created an issue here:
https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/687